# _setmode() throwing an exception that is not mentioned in the documentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception, visual-c++

The function where I use _setmode(), just takes a character such as 'K' and prints the unicode chess king for it. The output seems to be fine as well. The only problem is this exception. I tried looking up on the documentation of _setmode() but couldn't find the cause.

The code (I am using Windows' console)

```
void showPiece(char p)
{
    (void)_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    switch (p)
    {
    case 'p':
        wprintf(L"\x265F");
        break;
    case 'P':
        wprintf(L"\x2659");
        break;
    case 'r':
        wprintf(L"\x265C");
        break;
    case 'R':
        wprintf(L"\x2656");
        break;
    case 'b':
        wprintf(L"\x265D");
        break;
    case 'B':
        wprintf(L"\x2657");
        break;
    case 'q':
        wprintf(L"\x265b");
        break;
    case 'Q':
        wprintf(L"\x2655");
        break;
    case 'k':
        wprintf(L"\x265A");
        break;
    case 'K':
        wprintf(L"\x2654");
        break;
    case 'h':
        wprintf(L"\x265E");
        break;
    case 'H':
        wprintf(L"\x2658");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    (void)_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
}
```

Exception message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: ...\source\repos\bscs-21099-Chess\x64\Debug\bscs-21099-Chess.exe
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\lowio\write.cpp
Line: 626

Expression: buffer_size % 2 == 0

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170) says: "If you write data to a file stream, **explicitly flush the code by using `fflush` before you use `_setmode` to change the mode.** If you do not flush the code, you **might get unexpected behavior**."

Comment: You could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for copying the dialog text.

Comment: @Aziz I tried putting fflush(stdout) before and after using _setmode previously and it didn't change the error message that's why I removed it.

Comment: I called your function directly in the main function, and it didn't prompt the exception. Could you please provide the code that prompts the exception?